# Bug in Salary for Job Listing?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I recently saw a [job ad](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/369484/application-support-engineer-sg-digital) on Stack Overflow. What caught my attention was the advertisement claimed to offer jobs from **C$600k to C$80k**.

This seemed off for two reasons:

- Over half a million dollars of salary? Nowhere on the page is a job with a salary that high.
- Why is the higher number in the range listed first? Ranges are almost always ascending in a context like this, and in inconsistent with other job ads.

In case it's different depending on your region (I'm in Canada), here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: It could have been user error by whoever wrote the job posting. My guess is they meant to write 60K instead of 600K. Let's just hope that their payroll department makes the same mistake.

Comment: I'll note that I reported this because I expected that range to be auto-generated, not user entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salary information is not programmatic, it has to be entered by the hiring company. In this case, it's pretty obvious what they meant, so I went ahead and updated the info. Thanks for pointing it out!

In the future, you can flag the listing and we'll automatically get a support ticket.